# what should I use to show very large static content data ? UIView, UITableVIew or UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I want to show a large amount of content with images.

It is kind of blog which contains some information with pictures.

I don't have any API, I have to show/write data manually (Hard-coded).

So, which will be the correct way to achieve this?

1. UIView 2. UITableView 3. UITableViewCell

**For example** : Seen below image, this is the sample, same way I want to impelemt. It is just some view, it contain very large data. When you scroll it will display more details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not use a web view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's suitable to use `UITableview` with 2 custom cell one for images and the other for text , remove it's separator style and prevent selection give the label 10 margin from all directions and set `.lines` property to 0 , also use `attributedString` to set different fonts , colors to a specific range inside the text of the label

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to do some customs modifications like spacing, paragraph...etc. See the screenshot which I added, like this my requirement is there.

Comment: yes in dynamic tableView cells you can accomplish this easily will edit a photo

Comment: ok, @Sh_Khan. Let me check how to use dynamic tableView cells.

Comment: see edit .........

Comment: let me try this, it will help me or not.

Comment: this answer solves my problem. I used 2 custom cells one is for image and one is for text (content data).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using multiple UITableviewCell approach with core-text ability to render text as in the screenshots mentioned.

Also, I would like to highlight that UITableviewCell is having issues in calculating auto height provided NSAttributedStrings based rendering

Answer (score 0):

Can use tableview with custom cells. As its row height will be dynamically handled so no need to do much more complex process and easy to build.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIScrollView if the content will be static (e.g. header and content). Because using UITableView will be redundant.